# How to write predicate for column that has "or" in its name in ransack gem?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ransack

How can I write a predicate for a column that has `or` in its name? For example,
I have a column called `education_secondary_or_less`, and I want a predicate that will check whether the value is null, which I can write like this:

```
education_secondary_or_less_not_null
```

But I get an error when I write a predicate like that:

> undefined method `education_secondary_or_less_not_null' for #<Ransack::Searc